# Como conseguir que o jsoup passe apenas partes especificas do site?

Tags: java, jsoup

Como é que com o sou faço com que ele passe apenas a parte do 1,25€ para String?
https://www.pingodoce.pt/produtos/tab-choc-negro-nestle-100g/

Comment: Removi as tags android e android-studio pois o [**Jsoup**](https://jsoup.org/) é um *html parser* independente de onde esteja sendo executado. Tanto faz se é Android, desktop, web, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analisando o html, só há um elemento com classe `realprice` na página, então pode fazer um seletor por essa classe. Estou considerando somente a página que você forneceu na pergunta, como faltam detalhes é o que dá pra responder.

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.pingodoce.pt/produtos/tab-choc-negro-nestle-100g/")
                         .get();

// Pegando o índice "0" porque só há um elemento.
final String price = document.select(".realprice").get(0).text();

System.out.println("preço: " + price); // preço: 1.25€
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pode me explicar , o que faz o .realprice?

Comment: Como é que analisou o html?

Comment: Basta ir na página, pressionar o botão direito sobre o elemento e "inspecionar elemento". A maioria dos browsers possuem essa funcionalidade. Quando não houver, é só pressionar ctrl+u em qualquer página para exibir o código fonte. **:)**

Comment: `select(".realprice")` seleciona todos os elementos que possuem a classe `realprice` no html.

Comment: muito obrigado! felicidades resto de um bom dia me salvou mesmo